# How do i mock a function called inside of an import module?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, module, mocking

I'm trying to write a test for function foo() with jest.  I want to be able to mock the data returned from getFoo()

Here is an example of a module where a function Foo() calls getFoo(), which returns some data.

---foo.js---

```
export function getFoo() {
  //reach out to some API and get some data
  return 'foo data';
}

export function foo() {
  const data = getFoo();
  return data;
}
```

Here is the test i'm trying to make.

---foo.test.js---

```
import { foo, getFoo } from '../app/utils/asdf';

jest.mock('../app/utils/asdf');

const getFooMock = jest.requireMock('../app/utils/asdf').getFoo as jest.Mock;

it('should return NOT foo', () => {
  getFooMock.mockReturnValue('NOT foo');
  expect(foo()).toBe('NOT foo');
});
```

Test outputs
Expected: "NOT foo"
Received: "foo data"

I have been pulling my hair out over this all day. How do i change the output of getFoo() from within my test??